# Trying to pass an instance to a bound function C++

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-esp8266

This has got to be something simple, but I'm not experienced with C++ or bound functions.  Basically I'm trying to do this:

```
server.on("/capture", HTTP_GET, std::bind(&SolarCamera::serverCapture, this, server));
```

The problem is when I use the `server` instance argument.  Other similar binds without that instance are fine.

`server` is defined here as a protected method.

```
//SolarServer.hpp

class SolarServer
{
  public:
    SolarServer(int port);
    void startRouter();
  protected:
   ESP8266WebServer server;
};

//SolarServer.cpp

SolarServer::SolarServer(int port): server(port){}

void SolarServer::startRouter() {

  //capture cam
  server.on("/capture", HTTP_GET, std::bind(&SolarCamera::serverCapture, this, server));

...
```

And all I want to do is pass that `server` instance to the SolarCamera class so I can return a camera stream to that instance.  The camera interface is like this

```
// SolarCamera.hpp
class SolarCamera
{
  public:
    SolarCamera();
    void serverCapture(ESP8S266WebServer& server);
  protected:
    ArduCAM myCAM;
};
```

But the compiler balks at the method invocation and dumps a gnarly log:

```
error: pointer to member t
ype 'void (SolarCamera::)(ESP8266WebServer&)' incompatible with object type 'SolarServer'
error: return-statement wi
th a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your bind statement you're using `this`, which points to an instance of `SolarServer`, but, the method you're trying to bind to is of type `SolarCamera`. Instead of using `this`, you need to give it a reference to a SolarCamera instance.